# Casting to right object for tableView cells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I'm using tableView for displaying each tam tableView with different data.
when I coming back to the interface with all the tableView delegates i'm tantalizing the `*list` with a data (different arrays with fields) based on the the previous view

```
if(select = names )...
  list = myData.Names;
if (select = workers)...
  list = myData.Workers;
```

and so on...

and in the table delegates I use:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [list count];
}
```

But when I initializing the object for the table cells, How can I set exatcly the right object for the cell. now hard-coded I using:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
          cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"] autorelease];       
    }
    //HARD-CODED
    names *s = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = names.firstName;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=s.lastName;
    return cell;   
}
```

When i setting the `list` to `workers` how can I know to cast every time to the right object? without writing millions of `if`?

for example if

```
  if (select = workers)...
          list = myData.Workers;
```

the [list count] will return the right number but i want to display data based on the list, how can i cast it so it automatically declare workers

```
workers *s = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Why exactly do you want to cast?

Comment: The object for the cells, in the example i using names *s, but if i set my list to workers I need to set it to workers *s for using the worker fields

Comment: unable to trace problem....can you explain clearly..what is list,names..

Comment: Can you give examples of what the other classes bsides Workers look like? Do they all share the same interface, meaning: Do they all have a @property lastName, firstName, etc?

Comment: @pmd I edited the question, but no, that is the problem, Names have :lastName,FirstName... Workers: salary,company...

Comment: Ok, I think I get the problem, working on an answer right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I understand your problem, so let me try to explain:

This can be easily solved using protocols and giving the cell configuring responsibility to the actual objects.

First, declare a protocol that your clases will conform to:

```
@class MyTableViewCell;

@protocol CellConfiguring

- (void)configureCell:(MyTableViewCell *)cell;

@end
```

Now make some classes and make sure all of them conform to this protocol:

```
@interface Workers : NSObject <CellConfiguring>

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *company;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *salary;

@end
```

and:

```
@interface Names : NSObject <CellConfiguring>

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *firstName;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *lastName;

@end
```

etc...

In their implementation, each of them will handle the configuring of the cell differently:

```
#import "MyTableViewCell.h"

@implementation Workers

- (void)configureCell:(MyTableViewCell *)cell
{
    cell.textLabel.text = self.company;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = self.salary;
}

@end
```

and:

```
#import "MyTableViewCell.h"

@implementation Names

- (void)configureCell:(MyTableViewCell *)cell
{
    cell.textLabel.text = self.firstName;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = self.lastName;
}

@end
```

Remember the cell you receive is a custom cell that you created. For instance:

```
@interface MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (retain, nonatomic) UILabel *textLabel;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UILabel *detailTextLabel;

@end
```

Now, in your delegate call:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
          cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"] autorelease];       
    }

    id myObject = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([myObject conformsToProtocol:@protocol(CellConfiguring)]
        [myObject configureCell:cell];    
    return cell;   
}
```

And that's it. No more if-else statements and no more casting.

Tip: Whenever you start seeing too many if-else statements in your class, dirtying up your code, start thinking about responsibilities. Should the object be in charge of figuring out how to configure the cell? Or could we delegate that task to another object?

Comment: ,Its sounds to be the right solution, one thing...I created the protocol in a new interface, but when i'm implementing the protocol in each class they don't recognize the `textLabel.text`

Comment: You need a UITableViewCell subclass which has such a label. For instance MyTableViewCell, and then just #import "MyTableViewCell.h".


I thought you already had a custom UITableViewCell. Let me update my question.

Comment: Sorry cant get it... i'm creating the table in MyTable interface. I created a new protocol with this code: `@class Mytable; @protocol CellConfig  -(void)configCell: (MyTable *) cell`, but when i implementing it on each class i steel don't have the `textLabel`.

Comment: Try cell.titleLabel.text instead

Answer (score 1):

Set One flag in .h file like BOOL flag. Data will be filled according flag.

Intially flag will be TRUE in ViewDidLoad.

Now set list like this:

```
if()...
listNames = myData.Names;
if ()...
listWorkers = myData.Workers;
```

and in the table delegates:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 if(flag){
 return [listNames count];
 else
 {
  return [listWorkers count];
 }
}
```

---

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
          cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"] autorelease];       
    }
    if(flag)
    {
       names *s = [listNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       cell.textLabel.text = names.firstName;
       cell.detailTextLabel.text=s.lastName;
       return cell;  
    }
    else
   {
       names *s = [listWorkers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       cell.textLabel.text = names.firstName; // change for listWorkers
       cell.detailTextLabel.text=s.lastName; // change for listWorkers
       return cell;
   } 
}
```

Now when u want to change then

```
flag = FALSE; //worker data will be filled
[tableView reloadData]
```

Comment: well actually I have more then 20 types of objects..so I wanted to know how can i do it without all the if statements for the cells, thought maybe there's more simple solution for example some how in the first IF to initialize the cell

Comment: replace and use switch case for 20 different ojects

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the following solution ...

Create a custom object that conforms to UITableViewDataSource for each type of object. For example WorkerDataSource, NamesDataSource, etc...

Depending on the data you want to display, set the right dataSource for the tableView. An example from a project I work on ...

```
#define SECTION_HEADER_HEIGHT 20.0f


@interface FSMatchProgrammeDataSource ()

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *matches;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *groupedMatches;

@end


@implementation FSMatchProgrammeDataSource

@synthesize matches               = _matches;
@synthesize groupedMatches        = _groupedMatches;
@synthesize didSelectMatchHandler = _didSelectMatchHandler;

+ (FSMatchProgrammeDataSource *)dataSourceWithMatches:(NSArray *)matches
{
    FSMatchProgrammeDataSource *dataSource = [[FSMatchProgrammeDataSource alloc] init];
    if (dataSource)
    {
        dataSource.matches = matches;
    }
    return dataSource;
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return _groupedMatches.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSArray *matches = [_groupedMatches objectAtIndex:section];
    return matches.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MatchProgrammeCellIdentifier";

    FSMatchProgrammeCell *cell = (FSMatchProgrammeCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[FSMatchProgrammeCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];        
    }

    NSArray *matches = [_groupedMatches objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    cell.match = [matches objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    DLog(@"%@", cell.match);

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   // custom view created here ...
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return SECTION_HEADER_HEIGHT;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 44.0f;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (_didSelectMatchHandler)
    {
        NSArray *matches = [_groupedMatches objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        FSMatch *match   = [matches objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        _didSelectMatchHandler(match);
    }
}

#pragma mark - Properties

- (void)setMatches:(NSArray *)matches
{
    // matches property set, also an sorted / grouped copy is created for display called groupMatches ...
}

@end
```

And the dataSource is assigned in the tableViewController like this:

```
- (void)refreshView
{
    BOOL showInfoLabel = NO;

    switch (_tabBar.selectedSegmentTag)
    {
        case TabProgramme:
            _tableView.dataSource = _programmeDataSource;
            _tableView.delegate   = _programmeDataSource;
            break;
        case TabResults: 
            _tableView.dataSource = _resultsDataSource;
            _tableView.delegate   = _resultsDataSource;
            break;
        case TabStandings:
            _tableView.dataSource = _standingsDataSource;
            _tableView.delegate   = _standingsDataSource;
            break;
        default: break;
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```